# HERE maps Fleet Optimization shift times

Tags: here-api, heremaps, here-tourplanning

I am sending a request to the "tour plan" calculation that determines routes for multiple bus stops and buses as described here: https://developer.here.com/documentation/tour-planning/2.1.0/dev_guide/topics/concepts/problem.html. Depending on the route type, I either need the bus to drop all riders off at a depot at specific time or pick them up at a depot at a specific time. I see the shift time has a start time and optional end like this "2020-07-04T18:00:00Z".

1. Why is the date important and not just the time? This route will be used every day.
2. Why can't I just specify an end time and no start so the stop times are calculated from the destination perspective?
3. Does the calculation take historical traffic information into account for the time estimates?
4. Can we please add the TAG attribute to the fleet as well (like the tag in "job") so we can pass arbitrary information through to our consumers of the solution? (Example: my internal id of the destination or start waypoint)

Answer (score 0):

1. Tourplanning uses date to specify the departure time in routing request so it's needed as part of the API request.
2. With the current design making the start time optional is not supported currently.
3. The traffic setting configures what kind of traffic information should be considered for routing:

**liveOrHistorical:** for departure times in the future, either live or historical traffic data are applied depending on how far in the future the departure time is. For departure times in the past, only historical traffic data are applied. The departure time of a vehicle type can be configured via the vehicle profile's optional departureTime property. In case this property is omitted when defining a vehicle profile, the earliest shift start time of all vehicle types sharing that same vehicle profile is used as that profile's departure time. Choose this setting if all locations are within a radius of 190 km and you want to use live traffic data whenever possible.

**historicalOnly:** only free-flow speeds based on historical traffic data are applied. Choose this setting if you want to avoid live traffic data usage.

**automatic:** the same as liveOrHistorical, if all coordinates are within a radius of 190 km, otherwise the same as historicalOnly. Choose this setting if you want the service to decide automatically what is the best option.

Details are provided in this link:
https://developer.here.com/documentation/tour-planning/2.2.0/dev_guide/topics/concepts/configuration.html

4. No, that is left for pre/post-processing on the client-side.